# How to create a permissions model for accessing apps in a project?

Tags: django, models

I am creating a project with multiple services, each one represented as an app. I want to create a dashboard page where a user can see what apps they have access to, with staff users being able to add and remove apps via admin pages. What is the best model structure to do this? I.e. How should my models.py look? Is there a way to link such a table to the settings.py registered_apps tuple?

Comment: Django [build in permissions system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/) is working at an app level. It sounds like what you are looking for - I think you should read about it in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what django admin do.

You can use [django's permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) for that. Basically you assign permissions to groups and then you put your users in those groups (a user can be in several groups).